# ActiveStorage service_url && rails_blob_path cannot generate full url when not using S3

Tags: rails-activestorage

I have a basic ActiveStorage setup with one model that `has_many_attached :file_attachments`.  In a service elsewhere I'm trying to generate a link to be used outside the main app (email, job etc).

With S3 in production I can do:
`item.file_attachments.first.service_url` and I get an appropriate link to the S3 bucket+object.

I cannot use the method prescribed in the rails guides: `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(item.file_attachments.first)`

It errors with:
`ArgumentError: Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true`
I can pass it a `host: 'http://....'` argument and it's happy although it still doesn't generate the full URL, just the path.

**In development** I'm using disk backed file storage and I can't use either method:

```
> Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(item.file_attachments.first)
ArgumentError: Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
```

Setting host here also doesn't generate a full URL.

In production `service_url` works, however here in development I get the error:

```
> item.file_attachments.first.service_url
ArgumentError: Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
```

and specifying a host doesn't help:

```
item.file_attachments.first.service_url(host:'http://localhost.com')
ArgumentError: unknown keyword: host
```

I've also tried adding

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }
config.action_storage.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'
```

with no success.

My question is - **how can I get the full URL in a manner that works in both development and production?** or where do I set the host at?

Comment: Here there are more informations about this subject [github issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32500)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Active Storage’s disk service expects to find a host for URL generation in `ActiveStorage::Current.host`.

When you call `ActiveStorage::Blob#service_url` manually, ensure `ActiveStorage::Current.host` is set. If you call it from a controller, you can subclass [`ActiveStorage::BaseController`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a9692941600c34afbc8d60d15cb5f179d30f67e5/activestorage/app/controllers/active_storage/base_controller.rb). If that’s not an option, set `ActiveStorage::Current.host` in a `before_action` hook:

```
class Items::FilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action do
    ActiveStorage::Current.host = request.base_url
  end
end
```

Outside of a controller, use `ActiveStorage::Current.set` to provide a host:

```
ActiveStorage::Current.set(host: "https://www.example.com") do
  item.file_attachments.first.service_url
end
```

Comment: Thank you sir!  I got it working with this info.  Can I ask a follow up - if I don't want direct links to S3 is there a similar way to get a long lasting URL through the /rails/active_storage (redirection) endpoint?

Comment: Thank you, this saved me. I believe Action Storage and Action Mailer need update in docs since this is as I understand the only way to generate images inside an email body so email clients show them. Basically if to do it regular way, images will not be shown since actual `service_url` is required by email clients/service providers.

Comment: Very helpful for model testing!

Comment: How do you set "only_path: true" rather than a host?  Also, does ActiveStorage::Current allow setting the root as well?

Comment: "include [ActiveStorage::SetCurrent](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/app/controllers/concerns/active_storage/set_current.rb)" in the controller  will do the same thing as the sample above.

Comment: @IvailoBardarov what exactly is it doing? Simply doing what you mention in the comment worked for me but didn't understand why.

Comment: @stevec - Please open the link https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activestorage/app/controllers/concerns/active_storage/set_current.rb there you will see what you are including actually.

Comment: In Rails 7.1, you have to do `ActiveStorage::Current.set(url_options: { host: "https://www.example.com" }) { <code here> }` instead

Answer (score 5):

I needed the url for an image stored in ActiveStorage.

The image was

```rb
Post.first.image
```

**Wrong**

```
Post.first.image.url
Post.first.image.service_url
```

**Right**

```
url_for(Post.first.image)
```

Comment: They are different, though. The `.url` will return the service URL if the object is public. The `url_for` will return the redirect path.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for pointing this out, what exactly is the redirect path? (I was using the above methods to provide urls to the objects to an external site, so I think it did what I needed, but I will clarify it in the answer if it could confuse others)

Comment: The `url_for` will return something like: `http://www.example.com/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/xxxxxxxxx/thurman_senger.jpeg` whereas the `.url` will return `https://my_bucket.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?lots_of_things_if_the_bucket_is_private`.

If you are serving the URL of the assets through an API, you may want to serve the S3 URL directly to avoid extra hits to your server. Moreso if the bucket is public.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I had to force the port to be different due to a container setup. In my case the redirect done by ActiveStorage included the wrong port. For me adjusting the `default_url_options` worked:

```
before_action :configure_active_storage_for_docker, if: -> { Rails.env.development? }

def configure_active_storage_for_docker
  Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:port] = 4000
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 7.1 `ActiveStorage::Current#host` and `ActiveStorage::Current#host=` methods [are removed](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/7_1_release_notes.html#active-storage-removals)

But it's possible to use [`ActiveStorage::SetCurrent`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activestorage/app/controllers/concerns/active_storage/set_current.rb) module, it sets `ActiveStorage::Current.url_options` before action, so just enough to include in your controller (for example in `ApplicationController`)

```rb
include ActiveStorage::SetCurrent
```

---

This module source:

```rb
module ActiveStorage::SetCurrent
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_action do
      ActiveStorage::Current.url_options = { protocol: request.protocol, host: request.host, port: request.port }
    end
  end
end
```

---

Of course you can set these options yourself

```rb
ActiveStorage::Current.url_options = { host: 'my.host' } # and other options
```

Comment: If doing this outside of a controller in 7.1 (eg in a model), you can do the following:

`ActiveStorage::Current.set(url_options: { host: "http://localhost:3000" }) { <code here> }`